# How to get value from radio button dynamically

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i am creating a form for searching a client, using either id or email both are set to be unique. Application made on ***Codeignitor***.

1. I have created a form with two radio buttons, one for **search with ID** and another for search with mail+dob.
2. Depending on the radio button selected, corresponding input fields shown.
3. In controller, it choose the model function based on the radio button value.

This is I coded, i need to pass the value of radio button to `Controller.php` file

**Form(only included the radio button)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#usingdob").hide();
  $("#usingmail").hide();
  $("input:radio").click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "id") {
      $("#usingId").show();
      $("#usingdob").hide();
      $("#usingmail").hide();



    } else {
      $("#usingId").hide();
      $("#usingdob").show();
      $("#usingmail").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label class="radio-inline">
<input  type="radio" name="optradio" value="id" checked>Using ID </label></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label class="radio-inline">
<input  type="radio" name="optradio" value="mail">Using DOB</label>
</div>
```

I expected to get the radio button value correctly[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjmLQ.png)
[image]

Comment: To accept an answer, hover to the left of the answer and click the tick. When you have 15 rep you can vote up answers, but for now, pls accept an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**JS:**

```
$('input[name="optradio"]').click(function(){
    var optradio = $(this).val();
    //or
    var optradio = $("input[name='optradio']:checked").val();
    if(optradio == 'id'){
      //do your hide/show stuff
    }else{
      //do your hide/show stuff
    }
});
//on search button press call this function
function passToController(){
   var optradio = $("input[name='optradio']:checked").val();
   $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    complete: function () {
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('controller/cmethod'); ?>",
    data: ({optradio : optradio}),
    success: function (data) {

    }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#usingdob, #usingmail").hide();

$('input[name="radio"]').click(function() {

    if($(this).val() == "id") {
      $("#usingId").show();
      $("#usingdob, #usingmail").hide();
    } else {
      $("#usingId").hide();
      $("#usingdob, #usingmail").show();
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed is that you have 'mail' as a value in the DOB option. Another is that there seems to be 3 options and yet you only have 2 radios?

I adjusted the mail value to dob and created dummy divs to test the code. It seems to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#usingdob").hide();
  $("#usingmail").hide();
  $("input:radio").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() == "id") {
      $("#usingId").show();
      $("#usingdob").hide();
      $("#usingmail").hide();
    } else {
      $("#usingId").hide();
      $("#usingdob").show();
      $("#usingmail").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label class="radio-inline">
<input  type="radio" name="optradio" value="id" checked>Using ID </label></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label class="radio-inline">
<input  type="radio" name="optradio" value="dob">Using DOB</label>
</div>

<div id="usingId">
  Using Id div
</div>

<div id="usingdob">
  Using dob div
</div>

<div id="usingmail">
  Using mail div
</div>
```

As far as passing the value to the controller goes, ideally the inputs should be in a form. When you submit the form, the selected value can be passed to the php.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['optradio']))
    {
       Radio selection is :".$_POST['optradio'];  // Radio selection 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get currently checked radio button value Try below line which will return current radio button value

```
var radioValue = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
if(radioValue)
{
alert("Your are a - " + radioValue); 
}
```